# Error while using dpkt in python

Tags: python, pcap

I'm writing some code to parse a pcap file in python as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import dpkt
import sys
import pcap
pcapReader = dpkt.pcap.Reader(file("clients.pcap", "rb"))
for ts, data in pcapReader:
    ether = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(data)
    if ether.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP: raise
    ip = ether.data
    src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
    dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
    print "%s -> %s" % (src, dst)
```

While compiling, I’m getting the following error message::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dpkt
ImportError: No module named dpkt
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure dpkt was properly installed? If you have more than one Python installation, are you running your script with the correct one?

Comment: You can also set [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to include the directory it's in.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, just type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dpkt
```